# Custom tab name handle from admin

Tags: magento2, layout, catalog

I have created a module for custom product tab. It's working fine.

Now the problem is how can rename tab name by admin from admin side. Below is the screenshot. [image]

Below is the code catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom.tab" template="Vendor::product/view/details/custom_tab.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Tab One</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom.tab2" template="Vendor::product/view/details/custom_tab_2.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Tab Two</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom.tab3" template="Vendor::product/view/details/custom_tab_3.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Tab Three</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

How can we handle this for rename tab name from admin side.

Comment: Have you got solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pass helper class and function in custom tab**

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom.tab" template="Vendor::product/view/details/custom_tab.phtml" group="detailed_info">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="title" xsi:type="helper" helper="{Vendor}\{Module}\Helper\Data::getTabName"></argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

**Now create a function `getTabName()` in helper and return admin config value**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Helper/Data.php

```
public function getTabName()
{
    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
        'section/group/field',
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    );
}
```

**Check reference:**

[Pass Helper Class in custom tab](https://github.com/mageprince/magento2-productAttachment/blob/master/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml#L8-L12)

[Helper Function](https://github.com/mageprince/magento2-productAttachment/blob/master/Block/Attachment.php#L267-L273)

Comment: It's working. +

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It will be helpful for you.

**Step 1 :** Create a helper in your module `Namespace/ModuleName/Helper/Data.php`

```
public function getTitleFromConfig()
{
    Write your code
}
```

**Step 2 :** Then in your layout.xml you can get value using

`ifconfig="mbyte/mbyte_links/map_header"`